# Проверка вводимых значений в Web-форме

Tags: c#, asp.net, validate

Не могу разобраться с проверкой вводимых значений в Web-форме. Возможно, что-то я делаю неправильно.

Для примера можно взять шаблон Web-приложения из Microsoft Docs.
Tutorial: Create a Razor Pages web app with ASP.NET Core (исходный код - https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start/sample/RazorPagesMovie60) или Get started with ASP.NET Core MVC (исходный код - https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc/sample).

Как известно проверка осуществляется как на стороне клиента, так и на стороне сервера. Если использовать проверку по умолчанию, то всё более-менее понятно. Так как при запуске приложения, значение свойства System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture равно 'ru-RU', то данные выводимые в браузере соответствуют ru-RU (дата, числа). Рассмотрим форму создания нового фильма. Чтобы мы не вводили (или оставляли поля пустыми), происходит проверка на стороне клиента. Данные на сервер не передадутся, пока всё не будет введено правильно. Примечание на счёт ввода цены. Если ввести целое число - всё ОК. Если с запятой, то ошибка. Если с точкой, то клиентская проверка проходит и данные отправляются на сервер. Но сервер ожидает не точку, а запятую. Поэтому возвращает форму обратно с ошибкой. Всё логично. Что нам предлагает Microsoft? Вот это - https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-326590420 . Сразу скажу, перепробовал всё, что в основной рекомендации и в комментариях. Задача решается, но как-то криво. Объясню. Вставляем все нужные скрипты для глобализации и проверяем туже форму создания нового фильма. Если всё введено правильно (и даже цена с запятой), то всё ОК. Но проверка выполняется как-то странно. Пока мы ничего не введём в поле с ценой, проверка проходит на стороне клиента. Как только ввести что-либо в это поле (хоть текст или нормальное число), то данные формы отправляются на сервер. Даже если остальные поля пустые. По идее они не должны были пройти проверку. Ну а дальше сервер проверит все поля и если что не так, то вернёт форму обратно с ошибками.

**P.S.**
*Поставьте точку останова в начале метода отвечающего за POST-запрос. Станет понятно когда данные передаются на сервер. Это конечно очевидно, но вдруг кому пригодится :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы разобрался. Привожу решение. Может, кому пригодится. Для упрощения кода, сделал только для России.
И так, чтобы решить проблему проверки дат и чисел, формат которых отличается от американских, Microsoft предлагает следующее решение:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-326590420 .
Если использовать первое предложенное решение, то, казалось бы, всё заработало. Но, не так как планировалось. Задумка решения состоит в следующем. Использовать скрипт jquery.validate.globalize.js . Он подменяет стандартные методы проверки дат и чисел на свои. Стандартные методы находятся в jquery.validate.js . К слову сказать, что разработчики jQuery Validation Plugin не рекомендуют использовать их стандартный метод для проверки даты (предупреждение и рекомендации есть в коде и на сайте). Так вот, новые методы для проверки используют globalize.js, который использует cldr.js, а тот в свою очередь использует cldr-data (о чём умалчивает рекомендация Microsoft). Без наличия cldr-data, скрипт вылетает с ошибкой (видно в консоли браузера) и при нажатии на кнопку данные передаются на сервер. Соответственно сервер проверяет поступившие значения, и если что-то не так, то отправляет форму обратно. Подведём итог. Если использовать предложенное решение, то на стороне клиента будет происходить проверка только на отсутствие значений. Сами значения на стороне клиента не проверяются. Но возникает ощущение, что всё работает должным образом. Кстати в одном из комментариев к рекомендации было показано близкое решение, но тоже не совсем рабочее. Чтобы заработала проверка на стороне клиента, я вижу два варианта. Первый вариант использует специальную проверку, как дат, так и чисел. Второй только чисел.

**Первый вариант:**

Внести изменение в файл _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/cldr.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-globalize/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.when(
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/main/ru/numbers.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/main/ru/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/main/ru/timeZoneNames.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/timeData.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/weekData.json")
    ).then(function () {
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
            return result[0];
        });
    }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
        Globalize.locale("ru");
    });
</script>
```

Конечно, сначала загрузите недостающие файлы и проверьте маршруты к ним :).
Этот вариант подойдёт, если дата будет вводиться в обычное текстовое поле (<input  type="text">). Но, в моём случае (шаблон по умолчанию для ASP.NET Core MVC или Razor Pages) <input type="date">. Вот здесь кроется подвох. Браузер покажет дату и даст возможность её вводить в соответствии с текущими настройками для страны. В случае России это дд.мм.гггг . Но на сервер попытается отправить гггг-мм-дд . Что в данном случае не пройдёт проверку. В таком случае, можно либо отредактировать jquery.validate.globalize.js, либо использовать второй вариант.

**Отредактированный скрипт:**

```
// Tell the validator that we want dates parsed using Globalize
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var _date = new Date(value);
    var _value;
    if (_date instanceof Date) {
        _value = _date.getDate() + '.' + (_date.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + _date.getFullYear();
    } else {
        _value = value; // Хоть что нибудь присвоить :)
    }
    var val = Globalize.parseDate(_value, $.validator.methods.dateGlobalizeOptions.dateParseFormat);
    return this.optional(element) || (val instanceof Date);
};
```

**Второй вариант:**

Внести изменение в файл _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/cldr.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-globalize/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.when(
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/main/ru/numbers.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
    ).then(function () {
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
            return result[0];
        });
    }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
        Globalize.locale("ru");
    });
</script>
```

Закомментируйте или удалите метод проверки даты в jquery.validate.globalize.js (тот, что редактировали в первом варианте).
В случае с датой, вводимой в <input type="date">, то здесь браузер не даст Вам ввести неверную дату. А проверка пройдёт и через стандартный валидатор. Хотя это и не к чему.

А по мне, так лучше третий вариант. Убрать все client-side проверки. И всё будет работать нормально. Ну, будет чуть заметна задержка на отправку и получение формы.

**P.S.**

Если будете редактировать/экспериментировать со скриптами, не забудьте добавить asp-append-version="true". В противном случае, браузер будет брать скрипты из кэша.